# Need help creating a formula for dynamic average of last 4 weeks expenses

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am looking to create a spreadsheet that my staff fill out, it then gives me a master sheet with all the data, then I import dynamically to my financial spreadsheet telling me the average cost of my client over the last 30 days.

I am looking to create an `AVERAGE` formula of the last 30 days when Date = Today (Monday) (I want the weekday Monday as that's when staff hand in invoices)

Hope this makes sense, it's really tough!

Here's a video of me explaining my desired outcome

https://www.loom.com/share/3a9cb75052b246d1af2ba2f9ce9180a7

I've followed several guides & can't figure it out.

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(query(average(if(today() - weekday(today(),3)-30)))))
```

I expected $90 average and I just get blank

Comment: Although using a video to explain your question is a good idea, what happens if your video becomes unavailable, your question here no longer holds up on its own. You would be better of providing a detailed explanation of what you want to achieve, along with sample data and layout and your expected results along with everything you have tried so far,.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this formula:

> =AVERAGE(VLOOKUP(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1,A:H,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)-6,A:H,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)-13,A:H,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)-20,A:H,2,FALSE))

To break it down in to its component parts, the AVERAGE is taken from VLOOKUP results:

> VLOOKUP(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1,A:H,2,FALSE)

The VLOOKUP is looking for the last Monday from the current date:

> TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1

Then

> TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)-6

and so on...

When using on your sheet, you will have to specify the column you want to reference in your look up, for **colunm B (brand1)** use: **A:H,2,FALSE)**, for **colunm C (brand2)** use: **A:H,3,FALSE)**, for **colunm d (brand3)** use: **A:H,4,FALSE)** and so on...

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this! I appreciate it so much! looks really complex so I'm super glad you helped thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(QUERY({INDIRECT("A2:D"&ROW()-1)}, 
 "select avg(Col2),avg(Col3),avg(Col4) 
  where Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),    "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
    and Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-30, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"), 2, )
```

[image]